# Commenting out JSX in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, jsx

Is the a way to comment out selected chunks of JSX as you would with any chunk of html, css or JS?

I find myself constantly wanting to comment out a few sub components or something and usually resort to dragging them out of the render block, down to some unused part of the file so `cmd+/` will work again.

Comment: Did you install the language's support for Sublime. Like [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) for example

Comment: I don't use the language, but assuming it supports block comments this should either work out of the box by selecting the text first and using the block comment key binding, or you can update the appropriate config to add that if they're missing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add it to https://github.com/borela/naomi it required very specific meta scopes and a [plugin](https://github.com/borela/naomi/blob/master/plugin/commands/ToggleJsxComment.py) which is available in the latest versions of the package.